# Python dictionary with math symbols

Tags: python, dictionary, symbols

I want to make a dictionary in Python, but with math symbols (because then i want to plot that with the symbols).

So, i have something like this:

```
    dict_particles = {1: "Gamma", 
              2: "e+",
             -2: "e-",
              3: "mu+", 
             -3: "mu-",
              4: "pi0",
             -4: "pi+",
                  etc...}
```

Instead of the name "Gamma", for example, I want the symbol of the greek letter. Also i want to put super and subscripts to them.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what trouble you're having. Are you just not sure how to type Γ or γ? (Perhaps the easiest way is just to copy/paste it from somewhere.)

Comment: If you are using python3 then just copy paste the symbols in the python script and you are good to go.

Comment: What about using [Sympy](http://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/basics.html)?

Comment: I would suggest you update the question to something like "How do I print greek letters in Python" or "What do I need to do to print math symbols in Python" or something similar so that a person in the future searching for this information can find these answers; the dictionary part of the question is somewhat irrelevant to what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib.pyplot, you could simply use the syntax mentioned [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html):

```
text = r'$\alpha > \beta$'
```

Which matplotlib.pyplot will translate into pretty greek symbols, for example with

```
plt.title(text)
```

For your concrete example:

```
dict_particles = {1: r"\Gamma", 
                  2: r"\epsilon+", ...}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use any Unicode symbols in your Python code, even in variable names (applicable for Python 3.x, for Python 2.6+ look at [@a_guest's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827194/python-dictionary-with-math-symbols#comment76634957_44827274)).

You can also use unicode escapes (`"π"` = `"\u03c0"`)

Comment: For using non-ascii characters in the source code with Python 2 you manually have to set the encoding: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (at the top of the source file).

Answer (score 7):

What are you using to plot them? If you are using matplotlib, you can just write latex:

https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html

Then your dict might look like this:

```
dict_particles = {1: r"\gamma", 
              2: r"\epsilon",
                  etc...}
```

and matplotlib will replace the latex by the correct symbols.

Answer (score 4):

I have never tried to see if it is possible in other environments, but I achieved this using IDLE in python 3.x sometime last year; I used the [alt codes](https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/greek-alt-codes.php) to input the greek letters into my original code, so I would have it say

```
print("δ")
print("φ")
```

And they would print out as the literal strings without a problem.

Comment: If for some reason these don't work in your environment, @bakatrouble 's answer should be universal.

Comment: In Python 2 you can set the encoding via `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and then you can use non-ascii symbols too in the source code.